# Unusually high number of ports being used on my Linux computer

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, wireshark

I was experiencing slow network speed on a particular wireless router I share with some other people. So I ran Wireshark to collect packet usage to see what kind of ports most people are using, to try and find who might be abusing the network.

I used the Statistics->Endpoints report, and under the TCP and UDP tabs, I was surprised to find that my machine uses an unusually large number of "private" ports in the 44000-60000 port range, whereas virtually no one else are using these ports. I'm running Ubuntu 16, and have a few small databases running, but as far as I know, I shouldn't have anything running that should be using these ports. Should I be concerned about this?

Comment: Linux allocates ports for client connections from the upper range of ports, so when you connect to a website its usually from a port above 40000. Windows has in past started with ports above 1024, though in the most recent versions I believe they are starting above 10000. I'd use netstat to determine what process is creating those connections.

Answer (score 2):

Ports above 49152 aren't "private" ports, they're "ephemeral" ports, and they're typically what the OS assigns to client processes to use when initiating outbound connections.

Tools like `netstat(1)` and `lsof(8)` can be used to see which processes are using which ports.